# Appending lines for existing file in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, io

I want to add lines to an existing file in python. I wrote the following two files

**print_lines.py**

```
while True:
    curr_file = open('myfile',r)
    lines = curr_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print lines
```

**add_lines.py**

```
curr_file = open('myfile',w)
curr_file.write('hello world')
curr_file.close()
```

but when I run first `print_lines.py` and then `add_lines.py` I don't get the new line I add. How can I solve it?

Comment: There's a syntax error in the code. open() takes character arguments like open('myfile', 'w')

Comment: `open('myfile', 'w')` should open file in append mode `open('myfile','a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the code -

```
curr_file = open('myfile',w)
curr_file.write('hello world')
curr_file.close()
```

The second argument should be a string, which indicates the mode in which the file should be openned, you should use `a` which indicates `append` .

```
curr_file = open('myfile','a')
curr_file.write('hello world')
curr_file.close()
```

`w` mode indicates `write` , it would overwrite the existing file with the new content, it does not append to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

**On the print_lines.py:**

1 - You are looping forever, `while True`, you need to add a breaking condition to exit the while loop or remove the while loop as you have the for loop.

2 - Argument 2 of  `curr_file = open('myfile',r)` must be string: `curr_file = open('myfile','r')`

3 - Close the file at the end:  `curr_file.close()`

**Now in add_lines:**

1 - Open the file for appending not for writing over it, if you want to add lines: `curr_file = open('myfile','a')`

2 - Same as with previous file, Argument 2 of  `myfile = open('myfile',w)` must be string: `curr_file = open('myfile','a')`